# Grab some string from token in c

Tags: c, strtok

There's some code with token

```
char word[30] = "This - is - my - cat";
const char s[2] = "- ";

   char *token;
   token = strtok(word, s);

while( token != NULL )
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);}
```

so how to grab a string from token? for the example i want to grab "my".

Comment: what do you mean `grab`? do you need `strcmp()`? but then, beware of `' ' `(space)s

Comment: get "my" string to modify it. i don't think so, but if the solution need `strcmp()`, i'l use.
note : delimiter edited

Comment: `strcmp()` is to _compare_, not to edit. Read the man page.

Comment: Sorry, i did not get you, can you elaborate please?

Comment: I think that you meant `const char s[3] = "- ";` rather than `const char s[2] = "- ";`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need - this seems to be it -

```
char *result[8];  // 8 is completely arbitrary here
char *token= strtok(word, s);
int i=0;
char keep[12]={0x0};
while( token != NULL )
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      result[i++]=token;
      result[i]=NULL;
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
// get one of the fields you want "my" == result[2]
   strcpy(keep, result[2]);
```

result[] has to have enough elements to handle any number of substrings your code  will throw at it.

Comment: i appreciate it, but i'm confused about `keep[12]={0x0};` `result[8]` & `strcpy(keep, result[2]);`

Comment: It appears you are beginning C coding.  keep[12]={0x0}; initializes a C char variable, 12 characters.   I think anything we show you unless it does all of the things you believe you want will be of no help.  But.  SO is NOT a coding service.  The code above assumes "my" is the third element of the array of pointers called result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_TOKEN (10)

char word[30] = "This - is - my - cat";
const char s[3] = "- ";
const char str_my[3] = "my";
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_TOKEN];


int main()
{
    char *token;
    token = strtok(word, s);

    while( token != NULL )
    {
        strncpy(buffer, token, strlen(token)+1);
        {
            /* Now you have a local copy of your token in buffer. Do whatever you please with it.*/
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nope, assume we don't know there is `my` string at there, the score not just printed 852, but with sum.

Comment: Well, I'm only guessing now. It's not clear what exactly you had in mind. Here's a modified version of my answer.